# Umbraco websites and IIS Logging

Tags: iis, logging, azure, dns, umbraco

I have an Umbraco instance in the Azure cloud, v4.7 if memory serves correctly. I need to utilise IIS logging to obtain website usage statistics, but there appears to be a limitation.

I have multiple different websites, all using various website templates but the IIS logs don't appear to output the domain name. How can I get IIS to output the domain name?

Below is an example of what the current IIS logs capture (I know this is a BOT crawling the webpages, but I have genuine traffic but can't identify which website is visited):

2012-08-06 00:11:54 10.61.52.73 GET /insurance/insurance/ - 80 -
46.4.38.67 InnovantageBot/1.0+(http://www.innovantage.co.uk/technology/webmaster_information.htm) 200 0 0 390 2012-08-06 00:11:55 10.61.52.73 GET /insurance/reason/ - 80 - 46.4.38.67 InnovantageBot/1.0+(http://www.innovantage.co.uk/technology/webmaster_information.htm) 200 0 0 578 2012-08-06 00:11:55 10.61.52.73 GET /insurance/type/ - 80
 00:11:55 10.61.52.73 GET /life/qa/ - 80 - 46.4.38.67 InnovantageBot/1.0+(http://www.innovantage.co.uk/technology/webmaster_information.htm) 200 0 0 359 2012-08-06 00:11:55 10.61.52.73 GET /life/reasons/ - 80 -
46.4.38.67 InnovantageBot/1.0+(http://www.innovantage.co.uk/technology/webmaster_information.htm) 200 0 0 328 2012-08-06 00:11:57 10.61.52.73 GET /insurance/glossary/ - 80 - 46.4.38.67 InnovantageBot/1.0+(http://www.innovantage.co.uk/technology/webmaster_information.htm) 200 0 0 374

Answer (score 1):

In your WebRole.cs you can tweak IIS and each site running in IIS. You can choose which fields should be logged and I think you're looking for the `LogExtFileFlags.Host` field:

```
using (var manager = new ServerManager())
{
    var siteName = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id + "_Web";
    var site = manager.Sites[siteName];
    site.LogFile.LogExtFileFlags |= LogExtFileFlags.Host;
    manager.CommitChanges();
}
```

Make sure your role is running in elevated mode, change this in your **ServiceDefinition.csdef** file:

```
<Runtime executionContext="elevated" />
```

And you should also be able to change this setting using **appcmd.exe**:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/logFile#005

Comment: I tried to change "site defaults" programmatically using `ServerManager.SiteDefaults` - no effect. Changing `Site.Logging` worked.