# How do I enable cs-host IIS logging in Azure?

Tags: iis, logging, azure, umbraco, webrole

I have an Azure webrole, which hosts multiple Umbraco websites.

I want to enable "cs-host" logging from IIS, how do I code for this in the service definition?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the ServiceDefinition.csdef. You'll need to do this from the WebRole.cs or use a startup task.

- See my answer here: [Umbraco websites and IIS Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847282/umbraco-websites-and-iis-logging)
- This blog post also describes how you can do it using a startup task: http://joelfillmore.com/changing-iis-logging-fields-in-windows-azure/